# TFF :ValueError Error when checking model target

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I would like to implement a code of image classification with tensorflow-federated, So when I create the model and I pass it to federated averaging process, I find error that I can't understand here. Here is a part of my code implemented with TFF

```py
input_shape = (224,224,3)
def create_compiled_keras_model(input_shape, base_model='resnet18'):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_shape))

    base_encoder = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
      include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor=None,
      input_shape=None, pooling='avg')
    base_encoder.training = True

    h = base_encoder(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(h)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[h, x])
    model.compile(
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
    return model

def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model(input_shape, base_model='resnet18')
    return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch) 

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),client_weight_fn=None)
```

The error was:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['resnet50', 'dense_1'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [<tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32>]...
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Does the error occur if the model is called directly on `sample_batch`, e.g. `create_compiled_keras_model().test_on_batch(sample_batch)`? Since the model is constructed with two outputs `[h, x]` the code needs to ensure that `sample_batch` has two labels.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, so what is the solution? I must Change the output of model knowing that h is base_encoder and x is projection head ?

Comment: It would help if the question was extended to explain the intended model architecture. Image classification can be implemented without adding the encoder to the outputs, but is that the goal here? In such case the input data must contain training targets for both the `h` and `x`, if this is using the MNIST dataset likely only the labels for `x` are present. Is it possible to simply remove `h` from the outputs?